# Wordpress query by category name when the name has an & symbol

Tags: php, wordpress

Among the categories within the database of my WordPress driven website there is one that is named "Education & FAQs".

At some point, I need to pull all the posts related to that category:

```
$wp_query->query('category_name=Education & FAQs');
```

But what am I supposed to do about the "&" symbol? I've tried replacing it with & but still nothing...

Thanks for helping out!
Andrei

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the string you're passing in quotation marks?

```
$wp_query->query('category_name=\'Education & FAQs'\');
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does it trigger an SQL error or does it just not return any rows?  If it's the latter then it's because the data just isn't in the database (maybe the stored string isn't what you think it is)

Comment: It simply does not return any results. But the data IS store within the database. And what I've done to retrieve it before was to query by the category ID. This has worked, of course, but it's merely a sufficient solution, not the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

You can query on the slug. Go into wp-admin under Posts, and check out the Categories submenu. There will be a list of categories and their slugs. By default, yours will probably be:

```
$wp_query->query('category_name=education_faqs');
```